# .SDcols does on work on x.colname and i.colname prefixes

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to use a variable that has the column names of a `data.table` that is the outcome of a `non-equi join`.

If I use `.SDcols` to define the column names it throws an error on the prefixed column names.

How do I access these new columns that are an outome of the join?

See a reprex below.

```r
library(data.table)
set.seed(14)
dt1 <- data.table(id =c(1:10), height = rpois(10,170),weight = rpois(10,50))
dt2 <- data.table(id =c(101:110), height = rpois(10,170),weight = rpois(10,50))
# this works
dt1[dt2,on = .(height<height,weight>weight),nomatch=0,.(x.height,i.height)]
#>     x.height i.height
#>  1:      167      179
#>  2:      161      207
#>  3:      167      207
#>  4:      186      207
#>  5:      183      207
#>  6:      161      174
#>  7:      167      174
#>  8:      161      168
#>  9:      167      168
#> 10:      167      175
#> 11:      161      165
#> 12:      161      173
#> 13:      171      173
#> 14:      170      173
#> 15:      167      173
#> 16:      169      173
#> 17:      165      173
#> 18:      167      173

# this **does not** work
colnames=c("x.height","i.height")
dt1[dt2,.SD,on = .(height<height,weight>weight),nomatch=0,.SDcols = colnames]
#> Error in `[.data.table`(dt1, dt2, .SD, on = .(height < height, weight > : Some items of .SDcols are not column names: [x.height, i.height]
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
colnames = c("x.height","i.height")

dt1[dt2
    , on = .(height < height, weight > weight)
    , nomatch = 0
    , mget(colnames)
    ]
```

Comment: mget solves the problem, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The two approaches that you mentioned do different things. The error is normal and expected.
In your first approach `dt1[dt2,on = .(height<height,weight>weight),nomatch=0,.(x.height,i.height)]`, you are selecting the columns `x.height,i.height` on the *joined dataset* (which contains `x.height` and `i.height`). This in not the case in your second approach (`dt1[dt2,.SD,on = .(height<height,weight>weight),nomatch=0,.SDcols = colnames]`). Here is the definition of .SDcols as from the documentation (see `help(data.table)`).

> Specifies the columns of x to be included in the special symbol .SD which stands for Subset of data.table.

where x corresponds to x in x[i, j, by,...].

In your example, x correspond to dt1, which is not the output of the join but the left data.table in the join. So column names in `.SDcols` that are not in `colnames(dt1)` would return an error.

Also note that the prefixes `x.` and `i.` are useful when selecting columns in `j` and not when specifying columns in `.SDcols` (see argument `j` in `help(data.table)`).

> When i is a data.table, the columns of i can be referred to in j by using the prefix i., e.g., X[Y, .(val, i.val)]. Here val refers to X's column and i.val Y's.

> Columns of x can now be referred to using the prefix x. and is particularly useful during joining to refer to x's join columns as they are otherwise masked by i's. For example, X[Y, .(x.a-i.a, b), on="a"]

As an answer to your question *How do I access these new columns that are an outome of the join?*, One way is to proceed as @Sweepy Dodo did. Another way would be to use the dev version of data.table (1.14.3), which has a programming interface:

```
# get dev version
update.dev.pkg()

colnames = list("x.height", "i.height")      # note the use of 'list' and not 'c'
dt1[dt2, .j, on = .(height<height,weight>weight),nomatch=0, env=list(.j=colnames)]

    x.height i.height
       <int>    <int>
 1:      167      179
 2:      161      207
 3:      167      207
 4:      186      207
 5:      183      207
 6:      161      174
 7:      167      174
 8:      161      168
 9:      167      168
10:      167      175
11:      161      165
12:      161      173
13:      171      173
14:      170      173
15:      167      173
16:      169      173
17:      165      173
18:      167      173
```

Comment: thanks I will try this when I update to new DT next time.

Comment: @B. Christian Kamgang
eye opening explanation. Can I ask where you get your info on the dev package from?

Comment: You can find it in the data.table dev news ([HERE](https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/news/index.html))  or more about programming on data.table on [programming on data.table](https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/articles/datatable-programming.html#programming-on-data-table-1). Let me know if it is what you are looking for. Information about data.table (arguments): [HERE](https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/reference/data.table.html)